# Is there a plugin to use the fingerprint scanner on Android devices?

Tags: nativescript

So I know there is a [plugin](https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/nativescript-touchid) to use touchID on iOS devices but what about Android devices ? I've been looking around but I didn't find anything.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Haven't seen a plugin but the native code isn't too much :) you can check the accelerometer plugin for how to access sensors

Comment: See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), section with numbered list, item #4 in that list.

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge as of May/2016 their is no plugin for touch id on Android.  However the best place to find out if one exists is to check out the http://plugins.nativescript.rocks site as it nightly updates itself from all the plugins available in the community.

Disclaimer: I built the nativescript.rocks site.

Answer (score 0):

There is a [Fingerprint Auth](https://market.nativescript.org/plugins/nativescript-fingerprint-auth) plugin available now and this also works with Face ID on iphone.

From the command pront at app's root folder you need to run the following command to install this.

`tns plugin add nativescript-fingerprint-auth`